# Windows recycle bin extension to delete files older than 30 days

Tags: windows

When dealing with the Windows 10 recycle bin, I currently work this way when cleaning up deleted files:

1. Open the recycle bin folder.
2. Sorty by deletion date.
3. select everything that is older then *n* days (let's say 30).

I would love to semi-automate this task by having e.g. the following:

1. Right click on the recycle bin icon.
2. Select "Delete items older than 30 days".

**My question:**

Is such an extension or something similar available?

Answer (score 2):

### [RecycleBinEx](http://www.fcleaner.com/recyclebinex)

I use RecycleBinEx. It automates deletion of old files in your Recycle Bin with a custom duration. The options window is simple and easy to set up:

[image]

Features:

- Automatically cleans deleted files
- Integrates with the Recycle Bin context menu*

---

<sup>*It turns out that this feature isn't yet supported for Windows 10</sup>

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot, Timmy. I'll try that tomorrow.

Comment: Just tried it under Window 10. Unfortunately even after a reboot, [the Option to add to the recycle bin context menu is disabled](http://i.imgur.com/rYSoXqy.png).

Comment: @UweKeim I see. Does it still delete the old files automatically, or do you have to invoke it manually each time? If not, I'll remove the answer

Comment: Please don't remove your answer :-) I do think that someday an update will come out to fix this. **Update**: When starting the program as an administrator, the option _is_ enabled (although it seems to have no effect).

Comment: @UweKeim Good point! I have edited the answer to mention that

Answer (score 0):

Windows 10 has built-in feature already:

`Settings -> Storage -> Change How We Free Up Space`

[image]